# Error importing "matplotlib" - Windows Python3.7.4 32-bits

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, visual-studio-code, python-import

When importing matplotlib.pyplot as plt, it's unsuccesfully imported.

I have tried to delete Python, Visual Studio Code, all complements have been uninstalled and re-installed.

```py
import win32com.client
import sys
import os
import textwrap
import time
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This is the message that the terminal is presenting:

```
c:\Users\stsagale\Desktop\MasterThesis\Codes>python -c "import matplotlib"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\stsagale\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\stsagale\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\stsagale\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\stsagale\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\stsagale\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung
```

Comment: Looks as though `numpy` is the wrong bitness (32 when it should be 64 or vice versa). 32 bit Python cannot load a 64-bit DLL.

Comment: Thanks @BoarGules, i don't know how the 64 version was installed but it's not runnig. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try with :

```py
import numpy as np
```

Reading the error, I think it could matter.
Otherwise, did you use virtualenv (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/)?
It could help from preventing problem with collision.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv env
source /path/to/ENV/bin/activate
```

When you finish

```
deactivate
```